# How send multipart/fom-data with Volley and get a response in a JSON Object?

Tags: android, android-volley, json

I have a functionnal Android app send request with Volley and get response in JsonObject. Now, I need to include an image in my request and I don't have any idea how I can do that, and still receive my response in a JsonObject.

Thank you for helping.

Fabien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        JsonMultipartRequest<Upload> request = new JsonMultipartRequest<Upload>(Method.POST, apiUrl, mListener, mErrorListener);

        request.addFile("photo", image_path);

        RequestQueue mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        mRequestQueue.addRequest(request);
        mRequestQueue.start();
```

JsonMulitpartRequest is extended class of MultipartRequest where Override the below method to make it JSON object `parseNetworkResponse`

This is using library [VolleyPlus](https://github.com/DWorkS/VolleyPlus)

Comment: Thank you for this track but I was hopping to a solution with Volley himself because it's really well integrated in my project already. Do you think I can implement VolleyPlus easily without regression on my existant code with Volley ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can't valid it because I don't have enough reputation yet but I will come back when I can. Most important : IT'S WORKS. We just need to add request.addMultipartParam(name, contentType, value) for others params that are strings in the same request.